# jQuery button subscription does nothing

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to show search results in the same page. So I did this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="filter_id" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" id="load_results" value="Search" />
</form>
```

The problem is, when I click the button then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [document.ready() to ensure your function is getting called.](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#load_results').click(function () {
                 alert('hi');
                 var filterValue = $('#filter_id').val();
             });
         });
```

use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the default action or just return false at the end to prevent the postback..

This is what i have used and i can see the alert message.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#load_results').click(function () {
                 alert('hi');
                 var filterValue = $('#filter_id').val();
                 alert(filterValue);
             });
             return false;
         });
</script>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <input id="filter_id" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" id="load_results" value="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I guess it is not getting called. No alert window at all.

Comment: @James: I have added my aspx page code. Plz have a look. Hope it helps

Comment: Well found the mistake, thanks for this... I am stupid, didn't have jquery.min.js there....

Comment: thats what i was saying you to check firebug console for errors..:)

Comment: @James: I am glad you are able to find the error. Always use firebug, it is very powerful. And always paste your full code :)

Answer (score 1):

add `return false` at the end of event, so that the form not gets submit which will refresh the page by doing postback.

Do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#load_results').click(function () {
            var filterValue = $('#filter_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_Search")',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                data: { filter: filterValue },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#results_div').html(result);
                }
            });

            return false; // added to stop form submit
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This time nothing happens, It still won't show search results.

Comment: you need to check is ajax call is going check firebug console for errors

Comment: also post the action as well, it will be more easy to helpout

Comment: Edited the question. I've tested if the function is getting called with alert(), but nothing opens.

Comment: put alert in success call back function to check if success

Comment: Sorry for that :) I would accept more answers if I could :)

Comment: Well... found another problem, that filter parameter is not getting passed to action.

Comment: is the action called??

Comment: Yea, it gives results when the parameter is empty.

Comment: have your checked the filter value before ajax call whats coming in int?

Comment: Well I realised the action is not called, only the jQuery is called, but not action.

Comment: i was saying you check action is calling or not..:)

Comment: use this overload :``@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")``

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `type="submit"` from the button HTML. or return false in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try add return false to end your click event like this, and prevent default action:

```
$('#load_results').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var filterValue = $('#filter_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_Search")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { filter: filterValue },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#results_div').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This button is submit button so whenever you click on the button it causes page submit and the whole page is loaded again. you need to do either remove the **type="submit"** and add type="button" and also return false from the click function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#load_results').click(function () {
        var filterValue = $('#filter_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_Search")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { filter: filterValue },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#results_div').html(result);
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
</script>

<form id="myForm">
<input id="filter_id" type="text"/>
<input type="button" id="load_results" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$('#load_results').click(function () {
```

to

```
$('#load_results').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

This prevents the default action from happening, which in this case is adding a `?` to the end of the URL.